# TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation

Tags: python, opencv

I got an error TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation .
I wrote

```
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).parent
path /= "../../img_folder"
for f in path.iterdir():
    print(f)
    img=cv2.imread(f)
```

In img=cv2.imread(f), the error happens.Is this a Python error or directory wrong error?In print(f),I think right directories can be gotten.How should I fix this?

Comment: From which library does the `Path` class come from?

Comment: @Nitred from pathlib import Path is.

Comment: share your pathlib file content

Comment: @pankajmishra It is like ../../img_folder/photo1.png . Folder has images.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like `path.iterdir()` returns an object of type `<class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>` and not `str`. And `cv2.imread()` accepts a string filename.

So this fixes it:

```
import os
import cv2
from pathlib import Path
path = Path(__file__).parent
path /= "../../img_folder"
for f in path.iterdir():
    print(f)    # <--- type: <class 'pathlib.PosixPath'>
    f = str(f)  # <--- convert to string
    img=cv2.imread(f)
```

Comment: Feature request to add python pathlib Paths to cv2.imread and cv2.imwrite: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15731

Answer (score 1):

path is not a object of type STRING, is a object pathLib Type, so you have to do is, on the loop, cast the value of iterator in a String object with the method str() before to pass to the imread.

Like:

```
<!-- language: py-->
for pathObj in path.iterdir():   
    pathStr = str(pathObj) 
    img=cv2.imread(pathStr)
```

Comment: This tells the same thing as the much older answer and does not add anything new.